# Brochures font size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design

Hello This is may first question here. I was working with small projects. I have problem with the Brochures (Tri-fold).

At the Back Cover the content are only programme 2 fold and raffle entry 1 fold (i'm not sure what called for 3 fold). I don't have problem with this.

And the front cover is content the cover of our program and committee profile. My problem is it's OK to use a **smaller font** at the profile **around 4 to 5pt** since the whole member is almost 15 people with name position and description. Any advice since they what to put the description.

Comment: These are two separate questions. Can you please break them apart into two separate posts?

Comment: sorry for that i already edit my question.

Comment: What's the average audience demographic (age, sex, economic status)?

Comment: Actually this is for Conferences. mostly our audience are more on PHP Developer since this is PHP Summit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important factor to consider when looking at font sizes is the age of the intended audience.

Anything below 8pt type is very difficult to see for older audiences. And **4 or 5pt type may as well be invisible** because it won't be read at all. Most older audiences need a minimum of 11pt and a preferable size of 14pts to read comfortably.

Even when considering younger audiences, going below 8pt type shouldn't be considered for anything which needs to be conveyed directly to the reader.

I, personally, would never set any type below 6pt. Even then 6pt would be reserved for copyright notices or other content not meant to be directly read in the flow of information.

Another factor to consider where commercial printing is concerned is dot gain and intended stock. If you print on a stock which has a considerable dot gain, such as uncoated, standard offset, or newsprint, 4 or 5pt type is merely going to plug up and be unreadable anyway.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion and as for now my team choice make it in legal paper size.

Answer (score -3):

Use 11.5pt to be on safe side for body text. Based on that you will figure out how big you want the header to be.